# SQL Server : sort a 3 columns table into a 7 colums table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns `name, value, ts` like this:

[image]

and I want to transform it into a table with 7 columns `I1, I2, I3, P, COS, Wh, TS` like:

[image]

The data in table 1 is raw data, at every time stamp, there will 6 data being recorded. These 6 data (I1,I2,I3,P,COS,WH) is recorded under the column named 'NAME'. What I want to achieve is to sort these 6 data into 6 different columns and named it 'I1,I2,I3,P,COS,WH'.

Comment: please explain in detail what you exactly want. should i create new table table or from where i have to get values of table after treatment.

Comment: Have a look at [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You could also create a SQLFiddle for us, with the source and target tables already in place. That would make it a lot easier for us and less time consuming.

Comment: welcome to SO. please include samples in question not link it. have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Marco sqlfiddle is broken for mssql

Comment: Here's an alternative http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler

Comment: in the 7 columns table there are values I cannot find in the 3 column table, so this question cannot be answered without more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **PIVOT** AND **PARSENAME**:

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS Table(
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Value DECIMAL(15,2),
    TS Datetime
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I1',22.44912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I2',17.5628912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I3',9.6644912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.P',10102.935912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.COS',-0.83344912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.Wh',70011032,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I1',22.44912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I2',17.5628912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I3',9.6644912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.P',10102.935912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.COS',-0.83344912566,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')
,('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.Wh',70011032,'2016-02-07 18:50:00')

;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        PARSENAME(Name,1) AS Name,
        ROUND(Value,2,2) AS Value,
        TS,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS RowNo
    FROM @tblTest T
)

SELECT  [I1],[I2],[I3],[P],[COS],[Wh],TS from 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM T
) x
pivot 
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR Name in ([I1],[I2],[I3],[P],[COS],[Wh])
) p
```

Output:

[image]
**Note:** Date convertion logic is not included

Comment: I just tried the code, instead of giving me 3 rows of data, it gives me 8 rows of data with lots of 'Null' in the table.

Comment: I think you miss something, i have answer tested code

Comment: I had check my code with yours, nothing different. but i still cant get the correct output. by the way, i am using ms sql 2014.

Comment: i can get the correct output by deleting 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) AS ROWNO'.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know if my answer is the best one, but this came to my mind.
Create a procedure to do the following:

1- SELECT DISTINCT of the name column.

2- For each DISTINCT entry, select the data and save data in temp table.

3- Insert the data in the temp tables in order into one table.

4- Each data in the same row number will be in the same row on the new table.

i will try to find time to write the SQL procedure ASAP.

Comment: `EXTINCT` should be `DISTINCT`?

Comment: currently, my procedure is:

Comment: 1. save all the data into 5 different table 2. combine all the table (but there is some error, the rows are not matched due to some data is not being recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This should work fine

```
-- ---create table and insert data. i believe you have got the table already
CREATE TABLE #Sort (Name Varchar(30), [Value] Float, TS Datetime)

INSERT INTO #Sort
VALUES 
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I1',22.4491,'2016-02-07 18:50'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.12',17.5628,'2016-02-07 18:50'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.13',9.6657,'2016-02-07 18:50'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.P',10102.93945,'2016-02-07 18:50'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.COS',-0.833737,'2016-02-07 18:50'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.WH',70011032,'2016-02-07 18:50'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I1',22.56704,'2016-02-07 19:00'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I2',17.48134,'2016-02-07 19:00'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I3',9.73746,'2016-02-07 19:00'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.P',10067.5742,'2016-02-07 19:00'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.COS',-0.8270988,'2016-02-07 19:00'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.WH',70012768,'2016-02-07 19:00'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I1',22.60925,'2016-02-07 19:10'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I2',17.54026,'2016-02-07 19:10'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.I3',9.81285,'2016-02-07 19:10'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.P',10078.8154,'2016-02-07 19:10'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.COS',-0.8246349,'2016-02-07 19:10'),
('BLOCKE.SB_1_A.WH',70014472,'2016-02-07 19:10')

----use a vte to to select the data
;WITH Sordata
 AS
(SELECT
CASE WHEN RIGHT(Name,2) = 'I1' THEN 'I1'
     WHEN RIGHT(Name,2) = 'I2' THEN 'I2'
     WHEN RIGHT(Name,2) = 'I3' THEN 'I3'
     WHEN RIGHT(Name,1) = 'P' THEN 'P'
     WHEN RIGHT(Name,3) = 'COS' THEN 'COS'
     WHEN RIGHT(Name,2) = 'WH' THEN 'HW'
     END AS Names,
--Name, 
Value,  
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TS, 101) + ' '+ LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), TS, 22), 11)) AS TS
FROM #Sort
)
SELECT
*
FROM Sordata
PIVOT
(
MAX(Value) FOR Names IN ([I1],[I2],[I3],[P],[COS],[HW])
) AS PV1
```

Comment: 'SUM(Value)' changes the data (the data have more decimal value), I change to 'MAX(Value)', it gives me the original data. Thanks for your post.

Comment: How to save the PV1 table as a new table in sql?